# Issues with appending Item to container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a new item and price (two input fields) to a container. I tried adding a class to the parent element and than adding both items at the same time.

For some reason I am not able to make this work.

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
 // $('#groupOne').on('click', '.item', clickHolder);
 // $('#groupOne').on('click', '.item', clickCup);
 $('#addButton').on('click', '.addItem', addFunction);
}

function addFunction(){
 var item = $('.addItem').val();
 console.log(item);
 var placeIt = $('<td>' + item + '</td>');
 ('#groupOne').appendItem;
 $('.addItem').val('');
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" class="addItem">
  <input type="number" class="addItem">
  <button id="addButton">Add</button>
 </div>
 <table id="groupOne">
  <tr>
   <th>Item</th>
   <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Banana</td>
   <td>14.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Apple</td>
   <td>5.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
   <td>Tomato</td>
   <td>8.99</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors. First I'm not sure why you are using event delegation. Then you retrieve only the price of the item. Also you are using appendItem which is not javascript method as far as I know(I used jquery [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method on my snippet because you have jquery object but you can use javascript [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) on javascript object). I create the following snippet:

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
  //no need to use event delegation here. click event listener is enough
  $('#addButton').on('click', addFunction);
}

function addFunction() {
  //get item name
  var itemName = $('.addItem:eq(0)').val();
  //get item price
  var itemPrice = $('.addItem:eq(1)').val();
  //create jquery object
  var placeIt = $('<tr><td>' + itemName + '</td><td>' + itemPrice + '</td></tr>');
  //append it
  $('#groupOne').append(placeIt);
  $('.addItem').val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="addItem" />
<input type="number" class="addItem" />
<button id="addButton">Add</button>
<table id="groupOne">
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>14.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>5.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item">
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td>8.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I am learning more about jQuery now, But I appreciate your help and answer.